# Should I serialize my situation as a list or single objects?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a short question to more experianced developers.

I am using C# and I am in a bit of dilemma.

I have a list of objects which I would like to serialize into xml format.

For this I am using such a method which I have found out helpful, which is shown below.

```
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Then I have a list of objects (normally few hundres of instances, but could be up to few thousands) more or less containing parameters as below:

```
    2-3 integers
    1-2 DateTimes
    2 bools
    List<string> containing 1-5 short (1 word) strings
    string containing 10-30 characters
    string containing 30-1000 characters
    and maybe few short string more..
```

Then I am wondering if I should serialize the whole such a list into one xml file or it is better to serialize each object to seperate file. I am wondering mainly for purpose of stability (as I was counting it should not reach the limit of size of xml file, but I am not sure) and performance (I am a bit of scary that seperate files would multiply required time). Maybe there is some more aspects to be considered.

I would be thankful for the opinion of some experts.

Which way should I follow ?

Regards !

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how are you going to use serialized results. If you don't use serialized objects separately and always require whole list then go for one file.  Otherwise go for one file as well but if you find during testing that it causes issues with performance then it would make sense to review your architecture and use `XMLReader` or other type of storage such as database.